# awk to merge rows based on cell values

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to merge rows using awk where column 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 matches and combine unique entries from column 8 in it.

Input is

```
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0014L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0015L5;0017L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0017L5;0019L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0019L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/c-3885516020-20151008-00,infinity ,0007L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/cf_ABDB_02qj5qta_1_1_892529578,infinity ,0023L5
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0089L5
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0090L5;0094L5;0089L5;0091L5;
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0091L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/etc/,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/home/bblite/,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/home/bblite/,1 month ,0060L5
```

Desired Output

```
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0014L5;0015L5;0017L5;0019L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/c-3885516020-20151008-00,infinity ,0007L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/cf_ABDB_02qj5qta_1_1_892529578,infinity ,0023L5
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0089L5;0090L5;0094L5;0091L5;
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/etc/,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/home/bblite/,1 month ,0078L5;0060L5
```

Currently I using below code.

```
awk -F' *, *' '{a[$1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7]=a[$1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7] "," $8} END {for (k in a) {print k a[k] | "sort -u"}}'
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Consider the output as sample input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single ***gawk*** process:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" }
        { k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 }
        { a[k]=a[k]? a[k]";"$8 : $8 }
        END{ 
            for(i in a) { 
                split(a[i],b,";"); r=""; 
                for (j in b) { if(!c[b[j]]++) r=(r=="")? b[j]: r";"b[j] }
                delete c; print i,r 
            } 
        }' OFS=',' file
```

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` - comparison/sorting by array keys/indices. We are able to set predefined array `PROCINFO` to one of a set of predefined values. Those special values described here(documentation): https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning
- `k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7` - constructing a unique key
- `a[k]=a[k]? a[k]";"$8 : $8` - accumulating the 8th field value for each *group*

---

The output:

```
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/c-3885516020-20151008-00,infinity ,0007L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/cf_ABDB_02qj5qta_1_1_892529578,infinity ,0023L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0014L5;0015L5;0017L5;0019L5
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0089L5;0090L5;0094L5;0091L5;
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/etc/,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/home/bblite/,1 month ,0078L5;0060L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,1 month ,0078L5
```

Comment: @Siddi, It will do give unique 8 columns now, check my update

Comment: Perfect, Could you please break it down in detail? PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" are these inbuilt functions?

Comment: @Siddi, ok, added useful link. Take a look

Comment: @Siddi This solution have an error - compare last three rows its output and your desired output. Also, it removes comma delimiter between 7 and 8 fields.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have the same error and it was caused the unique values array. It should be cleaned for the each, new row.

Comment: @MiniMax, good point. Fixed. Now it's fine. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Let's first unique it `sort -u` then process it via `awk`.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=, '{cpyNF=$NF;NF--;a[$0]=a[$0]","cpyNF} 
    END{for (i in a) print i""a[i]}' <(sort -u infile)
```

Comment: I don't think (sort -u infile) will do any good, as each row is unique as a whole, its just the column 8 entries which are redundant

Comment: Your lines 5, 6, 7 are duplicated! it does remove duplicated rows, if you are sure those are unique at all, so better ignore it

Comment: Your solution doesn't  "combine unique entries from column 8 in it.", what OP was asking. But the nice trick with last field removing, I didn't know about it.

Comment: I see there is no column8 duplicated, column8 in each line is unique

Comment: Entries in the 8 column should be unique, not the column 8 itself. Look at this: `0015L5;0017L5` and `0017L5;0019L5` (second and third row). `0017L5` is duplicated and only one instance should be left in the combined row. Entries separated by semicolon. It was not said straight, but can be seen in the desired output, given by OP.

Answer (score 0):

#### First variant

`sed`, `awk` and `datamash` are used. I can add explanation, if you interested and the code does that you want. The rows should not contain `:` (colons), because I picked it as delimiter for `datamash`. Sure, it can be changed to other.

```
sed 's/,/:/7' input.txt |
datamash -t: -g 1 unique 2 | 
awk -F: '{
    printf "%s,", $1;

    size = split($2, arr, "[,;]");

    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        if(!unique_arr[arr[i]]) {
            printf "%s; ", arr[i];
            unique_arr[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    print "";
    delete unique_arr;
}' | sed 's/[; ]*$//g'
```

**Output**

```
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0014L5; 0015L5; 0017L5; 0019L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/c-3885516020-20151008-00,infinity ,0007L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/cf_ABDB_02qj5qta_1_1_892529578,infinity ,0023L5
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0089L5; 0090L5; 0094L5; 0091L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/etc/,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/home/bblite/,1 month ,0060L5; 0078L5
```

#### Second variant - without datamash

```
sed 's/,/:/7; s/\s*;$//' input.txt |
awk -F: '
{
    size = split($2, arr_eight_field, ";"); 
    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        main_arr[$1][arr_eight_field[i]] = 1;
    }
}
END {
    for(seven_fields in main_arr) {
        eight = "";
        for(i in main_arr[seven_fields]) {
            eight = (eight) ? eight "; " i : i;
        }
        print seven_fields "," eight;
    }
}' | sort
```

**Output**

```
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/c-3885516020-20151008-00,infinity ,0007L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,10/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/cf_ABDB_02qj5qta_1_1_892529578,infinity ,0023L5
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/01/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,infinity ,No_Media_Used/Disk
AB-DB1,No_IP_Found,11/08/2015,INFINITY,Adhoc-ab-db1-Sunset,/avqln1ic_1_1,infinity ,0017L5; 0015L5; 0019L5; 0014L5
APPSRV,172.25.128.100,09/11/2017,12/13/2017,MG16-Genral-OS-LINUX-MONTHLY,/;/Monitoring/;/Monitoring_old/;/NetBackup_7.5_CLIENTS.tar;/bin/;/boot/;/data1/;/data2/;/dev/;/etc/;/home/;/lib/;/lib64/;/lost+found/;/media/;/misc/;/mnt/;/net/;/opt/;/proc/;/root/;/sbin/;/selinux/;/srv/;/sys/;/tftpboot/;/tmp/;/usr/;/var/,3 months ,0090L5; 0089L5; 0091L5; 0094L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,DB_Backup/Archived/Offline,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/etc/,1 month ,0078L5
BB-LITE,172.25.129.32,09/25/2017,10/26/2017,MG12-BB-LITE-AP-BROKER-DAILY,/home/bblite/,1 month ,0060L5; 0078L5
```